# Unit testing EF Core using in-memory database with an eager-loaded function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I am writing unit tests for my my Web API and cannot get the test to pass except by  removing the include (eager-loading from the method). I am using the in-memory database to provide the `dbcontext` and can't figure out why it is returning no data. Thanks in advance for any help or constructive criticism

This is the method I am trying to test.
**Note**: it passes the test if I comment out the `.include` statements.

```
    public async Task<LibraryAsset> GetAsset(int assetId)
    {
        var asset = await _context.LibraryAssets
            .Include(p => p.Photo)
            .Include(p => p.Category)
            .Include(a => a.AssetType)
            .Include(s => s.Status)
            .Include(s => s.Author)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == assetId);

        return asset;
    }
```

This is the base `DbContext` using the inMemory DB:

```
    public DataContext GetDbContext()
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();

        if (useSqlite)
        {
            // Use Sqlite DB.
            builder.UseSqlite("DataSource=:memory:", x => { });
        }
        else
        {
            // Use In-Memory DB.
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        var DataContext = new DataContext(builder.Options);

        if (useSqlite)
        {
            // SQLite needs to open connection to the DB.
            // Not required for in-memory-database and MS SQL.
            DataContext.Database.OpenConnection();
        }

        DataContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        return DataContext;
    }
```

This is the test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async void GetAssetById_ExistingAsset_ReturnAsset()
    {
        using (var context = GetDbContext())
        {
            ILogger<LibraryAssetService> logger = new 
            NullLogger<LibraryAssetService>();

            var service = new LibraryAssetService(context, _logger);

            var asset = new LibraryAsset
            {
                Id = 40,
                NumberOfCopies = 20,
                Title = "",
                Year = 1992,
                Status = new Status { Id = 1 },
                AssetType = new AssetType { Id = 1 },
                Author = new Author { Id = 1 },
                Category = new Category { Id = 2 },
                Photo = new AssetPhoto { Id = 1 }
            };

            context.LibraryAssets.Attach(asset);

            context.Add(asset);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var actual = await service.GetAsset(40);
            Assert.Equal(40, actual.Id);
        }
    }
```

This is my first time writing unit tests and I am basically learning as I go. Please feel free to point out any other mistakes that you may have noticed as well.

Comment: Do you get any error or unexpected result? I made a test with your code, but fail to reproduce your issue. Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

1. If your real databse is relational avoid using `UseInMemoryDatabase` database for testing because it doesn't support relational behaviours.
2. Separate the Arrange contexts from the Act contexts. That means, create a new DataContext for preparing the test, adding test data, and etc, and create another one for SUT (`LibraryAssetService` in this case). `DbContext` stores local data (in memory) which may not exist in the database and that could show fake green tests in some scenarios!
3. You don't need `Attach` when you're adding the assets. That could create `Foreign key constraint` error with sqlite.

I removed some of your navigations and parameters for the sake of simplicity. So lets suppose the `LibraryAssetService` is something like this:

```
public class LibraryAssetService
{
  public LibraryAssetService(DataContext context)
  {
     _context = context;
  }

  private readonly DataContext _context;

  public async Task<LibraryAsset> GetAsset(int assetId)
  {
     var asset = await _context.LibraryAssets
        .Include(p => p.Photo)
        .Include(s => s.Author)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == assetId);

     return asset;
  }
}
```

The test class:

```
public class LibraryAssetServiceTests
{
  public LibraryAssetServiceTests()
  {
     _factory = new TestDataContextFactory();
  }

  private TestDataContextFactory _factory;

  [Fact]
  public async void GetAssetById_ExistingAsset_ReturnAsset()
  {
     // Arrange
     using (var context = _factory.Create())
     {
        var asset = new LibraryAsset
        {
           Id = 40,
           Author = new Author { Id = 1 },
           Photo = new Photo { Id = 1 }
        };

        context.Add(asset);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }

     // Act
     using (var context = _factory.Create())
     {
        var service = new LibraryAssetService(context);
        var actual = await service.GetAsset(40);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(40, actual.Id);
        Assert.Equal(1, actual.Author.Id);
        Assert.Equal(1, actual.Photo.Id);
     }

  }
}
```

And finally, a little helper class to prepare the `DataContext` for your tests. It's good practice to extract these kind of things outside your test classes. **The important** thing to remember when testing with sqlite memory databases is that you should keep the connection open during the test. No matter how many `DbContext` instances you create. The xUnit create an instance of the test class for each test method. So an instance of `TestDataContextFactory` will be created for each test, and you are good to go.

```
public class TestDataContextFactory
{
  public TestDataContextFactory()
  {
     var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
     var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
     connection.Open();
     builder.UseSqlite(connection);

     using (var ctx = new DataContext(builder.Options))
     {
        ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
     }

     _options = builder.Options;
  }

  private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

  public DataContext Create() => new DataContext(_options);
}
```

Comment: I am getting a foreign key restriction error after using your code. I tried adding the suppressForeignkeyenforcement but that still did not help

Comment: create a github repo, I will check it. The code worked ok on my machine. Make sure you are not using the `Attach()` method.

Comment: This is the link to the github repo [link](https://github.com/lawrencefej/LibraryManagementAPI/blob/master/LibraryManagementSystem.Tests/Services/LibraryAssetServiceShould.cs)

Comment: @lawrencefejokwu make breakpoint at line 34 of  `LibraryAssetService` and watch your `asset` object. As you see there are lots of `0` values for foreign key values like  `StatusId`, `AssetTypeId`, or `AuthorId`. That's why the foreign key restriction is happening. There is no Author in the database with ID of 0!  I commented out all the foreign keys in `LibraryAsset` and made the test to run with Sqlite, and it was green! Make sure you initialize your asset object with whatever it needs and you are good to go.

Comment: @lawrencefejokwu and one more thing: I checked the `DataContext` class, you didn't configure the asset entity. Define the entity relations for EF, that could make your entities much smaller and clearer. And be aware of the seeding in `OnModelCreating` method. It can cost you performance issues.

Comment: you were right, everything is working as expected. i will look into refactoring the DataContext eventually, although this is really just a side project that i am using to learn .net core and not necessarily going into PROD. however i do want to make sure i am learning the best practices. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Your welcome @lawrencefejokwu! .NET Core is fun to learn. Have fun!