# Moq a service or service interface with a db context for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

So I've trying to test my webapp coded in .net core 5.0, and I have a classic MVC model with service classes. Now I am trying to unit test the solution with moq to mock my database, and my tests run, but I have just noticed that they are all wrong when I debug. It seems as if it doesn't actually connect to the mock service or database itself... I have gone for mocking the service interface but that doesn't seem to work still. Help would be greatly appreciated.

**Service class:**

```
public class InventoryService : IInventoryService
{
    private readonly DBContext _db;

    public InventoryService(DBContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<Inventory> GetInventories(string id)
    {
        var inventories = (from i in _db.Inventories where i.userId.Equals(id) select i).ToList();
        return inventories;
    }

    public void CreateInventory(Inventory newInventory)
    {
        _db.Inventories.Add(newInventory);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public bool DeleteInventory(Guid Id, string UserId)
    {
        var inventory = _db.Inventories.Find(Id);

        if (inventory == null)
            return false;

        if (inventory.userId != UserId)
            return false;

        //Delete items using item service
        var items = from i in _db.Items where i.inventoryId.Equals(Id) select i;
        foreach(var i in items)
        {
            _db.Items.Remove(i);
        }

        _db.Inventories.Remove(inventory);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

**Service interface it uses:**

```
public interface IInventoryService
{
    public List<Inventory> GetInventories(string id);
    public void CreateInventory(Inventory newInventory);
    public bool DeleteInventory(Guid Id, string UserId);
}
```

}

**Model:**

```
public class Inventory
{
    // The Id field is a unique identifier for a specific inventory
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // The name of the Inventory. Required to have a value
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Inventory Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public string userId { get; set; }
}
```

}

**Unit test:**

```
public class InventoryTests
{

    // Unit test defined for the get user inventories, a valid ID will always be passed in so no need for negative testing
    [Fact]
    public void Get_user_inventories_with_valid_id()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        Guid theId1 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
        Guid theId2 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");

        string u1 = "xxx";
        string u2 = "yyy";

        var mockIn = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

        var data = new List<Inventory>
        {
            new Inventory { Id = theId1, name = "Mums 1", userId = u1},
            new Inventory { Id = theId1, name = "Mums 1.2", userId = u1},

        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Inventory>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        Mock<IInventoryService> myser = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

        //ACT

        myser.Setup(x => x.GetInventories(u1)).Returns(mockSet.Object.ToList());

        var tinvs = myser.Object.GetInventories(u1);


        //ASSERT
        Assert.Equal(2 , tinvs.Count);

    }


    //Unit test for creating an inventory, a valid new inventory object will always be passed in so need for negative testing
    [Fact]
    public void Creating_An_Inventory()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        Guid theId2 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");

        string u1 = "xxx";
        string u2 = "yyy";

        var mockIn = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

        var data = new List<Inventory>
        {

        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Inventory>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        //ACT

        Mock<IInventoryService> myser = new Mock<IInventoryService>();
        myser.Setup(x => x.GetInventories(u1)).Returns(mockSet.Object.ToList());

        Inventory thenew = new Inventory { Id = theId2, name = "Mums 2", userId = u2 };
        myser.Object.CreateInventory(thenew);


        //ASSERT
        Assert.NotNull(data);
    }


    //Unit test for deleting an inventory. It will always be valid because a guid and user id will be passed in automatically 
    [Fact]
    public void Deleting_An_Inventory()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        Guid theId1 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
        Guid theId2 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");


        string u1 = "123";


        //var mockIn = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

        var data = new List<Inventory>
        {
            new Inventory { Id = theId1, name = "testinv 1", userId = u1},

        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Inventory>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        //ACT

        Mock<IInventoryService> myser = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

        myser.Setup(x => x.GetInventories(u1)).Returns(mockSet.Object.ToList());


        myser.Object.DeleteInventory(theId1, u1);

        var updInvs = myser.Object.GetInventories(u1);
        int x = updInvs.Count;

        //ASSERT
        Assert.Equal(0, x);
    }

}
```

}

I am fairly sure it is a minor error in my setup of the unit test's mocking. any help would be great.

Comment: Can you clear, what you want to test? Because now you are mock everything and trying to test your mocks.

Comment: I wanted to test my services versus my mock db, and now I understand that I'm mocking everything so nothing is happening. Thank you for taking the time to check though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to test your InventoryService, you have to mock your dbContext as you do. Better use `EF InMemoryDatabase` like Microsoft advises https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#unit-testing

About your tests, I make a few modifications, to test `InventoryService`. It passes in debug mode.

```
public class InventoryService : IInventoryService
    {
        private readonly DBContext _db;

        public InventoryService(DBContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public List<Inventory> GetInventories(string id)
        {
            //i change inventories to _db.Set<Inventory> which able to be mock
            var inventories = (from i in _db.Set<Inventory>() where i.userId.Equals(id) select i).ToList();
            return inventories;
        }
        //ANOTHER CODE
}
```

```
        [Fact]
        public void Get_user_inventories_with_valid_id()
        {
            //ARRANGE
            Guid theId1 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
            Guid theId2 = new("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");

            string u1 = "xxx";
            string u2 = "yyy";

            var mockIn = new Mock<IInventoryService>();

            var data = new List<Inventory>
            {
                new Inventory { Id = theId1, name = "Mums 1", userId = u1 },
                new Inventory { Id = theId1, name = "Mums 1.2", userId = u1 },
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Inventory>>();
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<Inventory>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());


            //HERE
            var dbMock = new Mock<DBContext>();
            dbMock.Setup(x => x.Set<Inventory>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
            var myser = new InventoryService(dbMock.Object);

            //ACT
            //AND HERE
            var tinvs = myser.GetInventories(u1);


            //ASSERT
            Assert.Equal(2, tinvs.Count);
        }
```

If you want to make InMemory db or test on real SQL db, you look at these questions.
[Unit testing EF Core using in-memory database with an eager-loaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469212/unit-testing-ef-core-using-in-memory-database-with-an-eager-loaded-function)
[Unit testing with EF Core and in memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264787/unit-testing-with-ef-core-and-in-memory-database)

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot and I can definitely fix my unit tests now for project day!